# How In Running multiple Web Server on Multi Server at one static IP

Tags: web

I Have one static Ip such as 1233.22.33.44 and i have two Servers that have IP:
Server 1: 192.168.1.1
Server 2: 192.168.1.2

Server 1 running Website on Port default 80, I can access Web on Server 1 through http://1233.22.33.44 , and I want set up Web Server Running on Server 2, how can i do that? 
Thanks for Reply!

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions: load balancing (keepalived for instance) or reverse proxy (apache or nginx for instance).

Here is a sample configuration for nginx as a reverse proxy:

```
upstream backend {
        ip_hash;
        server 192.168.1.1;
        server 192.168.1.2;

}

upstream sorry {
        server public_ip;
}


server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

        location / {
                error_page 502 504 = @fallback;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout 150;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location @fallback {
                proxy_pass http://sory;
        }
}
```